# How to convert PHP get query to Meteor's HTTP.get()?

Tags: javascript, php, http, meteor

I have a sample php query that retrieves data from the API:

```
$http = new Client();

 $response = $http->get('https://connection.toserver.com', [ 'GetRequest' => [
                      'identifier'  => '123',
                      'identifierType' => 'code',
                     'language' => 'eng',
                     'maxCount' => 1,
                     'contain' => ['name', 'lastname', 'age']
               ] 
            ], 
           [
           'headers' => [
                'API-LANGUAGE' => 'eng',
               'API-CALL-NAME' => 'Get', 
               'API-AUTH-TOKEN'  => 'somerandomtoken']
 ]
 );
```

How can I make the same request from a Meteor server-side function using HTTP package? My last attempt looked like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
getItemByEAN: function(code) {
    check(code, String);
    this.unblock();
    var x = HTTP.get(url,
      {headers:{
         "API-LANGUAGE": "eng",
         "API-CALL-NAME": "Get",
         "API-AUTH-TOKEN": "somerandomtoken"
          },
        data: {
          identifier: code,
          identifierType: 'code',
          language: 'eng',
          maxCount: 1,
          contain: ['name', 'lastname', 'age']
         }
     });
     return(x);
    }
});
```

This code resulted in server error "ReferenceError: data is not defined" I am using meteor docs (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call) as a reference but with no success so far.

Thank You in advance

EDIT: I've updated the current meteor example to show full Meteor.methods() section

Comment: You're missing a method, try adding that first. It's likely the rest will work based on what I can glean fro the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your server expects, but one difference I see is that in php you wrap the data in a "GetRequest" object. Have you tried this:

```
HTTP.get(url,
  {headers:{
     "API-LANGUAGE": "eng",
     "API-CALL-NAME": "Get",
     "API-AUTH-TOKEN": "somerandomtoken"
      },
    data: { GetRequest: {
       identifier: 123,
      identifierType: 'code',
      language: 'eng',
      maxCount: 1,
      contain: ['name', 'lastname', 'age']
    }}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've adjusted the method according to your suggestions and now I'm getting a "Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
". Is there a way to avoid it without reducing the level of security of the system?

Comment: that question regards the server you are GETing from more than your code. I don't know what the error message means. I don't think it's a meteor error message. Can't help you with that, sorry.

Comment: I allowed unauthorized access to APIs in order to eliminate this error, but now i'm getting "Exception while invoking method 'getItemByEAN' ReferenceError: data is not defined" again